# What is the Golden Standard of Testing Fluid Intelligence?

Tags: intelligence, test

Not much to add to the title- what is the currently accepted "best" test of fluid intelligence? How was it determined to be the best?

Comment: I don't think there is a "best". WAIS is one widely used, and according to its Wikipedia page, the most widely used.

Comment: What is your criteria for "best"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find an answer here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_and_crystallized_intelligence#Measurement_of_fluid_intelligence

As it mentions, Raven's Progressive Matrix is a popular option that has been shown to load highly on both g and Gf (fluid intelligence).

In terms of gold standard, it is probably preferable to have a battery of measures that are relevant to Gf and take some composite of these. For example, the WAIS performance subscales.

In general, a good measure of fluid intelligence would be inferred from its correlations with other measures. It should also have good reliability and other validity properties. Specifically, when administered in a large battery of cognitive ability measures, a factor analysis should indicate that the test loads highly on a factor that looks like fluid intelligence (i.e., that other measures of fluid intelligence load on). There's more to it than that, but perhaps a starting point.